# Replacing the one child node value which is exists multiple places with in XML

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, replace, qxmlquery

I need to replace the values 'OBLIGEE ATTORNEY' and 'saravanan' of child node <var..> by the value 'EDWIN CHAND'.

```
BEGIN
DECLARE @LS_EXECUTEQUERY_DESC NVARCHAR(4000),
        @LS_NODE_NAME VARCHAR(100)='user_input_attn_obligee_desc',
        @LS_NAME_DESC  VARCHAR(100) = 'EDWIN CHAND',
        @LS_DOCUMENT_XML XML=cast('<root>
<first>                                                                               
   <var name="user_input_attn_obligee_desc">OBLIGEE ATTORNEY</var> 
</first> 
<second>
 <var name="user_input_attn_obligee_desc">saravanan</var> 
</second>   
<user_input_attn_obligor_desc>OBLIGOR ATTORNEY</user_input_attn_obligor_desc>                          
</root>' AS XML);

 SET @LS_EXECUTEQUERY_DESC = 'SET @LS_DOCUMENT_XML.modify(''replace value of (/root//var[contains(@name,"'+(@LS_NODE_NAME)+'")] /text())[1] with "'+CAST(ISNULL(@LS_NAME_DESC,'') AS VARCHAR)+'"'')';  
 EXEC SP_EXECUTESQL @stmt = @LS_EXECUTEQUERY_DESC ,@params = N'@LS_DOCUMENT_XML xml OUTPUT' ,@LS_DOCUMENT_XML = @LS_DOCUMENT_XML OUTPUT;

             SET @LS_EXECUTEQUERY_DESC = CAST (@LS_DOCUMENT_XML AS VARCHAR(MAX)); 
             SELECT @LS_EXECUTEQUERY_DESC;

END;
```

But the above query replace the first occurrence alone not all occurrences. Even it didn't throw any error. Could please some one help me to do this. Thanks in advance.

```
Needed OUTPUT:
            *<root>
            <first>                                                                               
               <var name="user_input_attn_obligee_desc">EDWIN CHAND</var> 
            </first> 
            <second>
             <var name="user_input_attn_obligee_desc">EDWIN CHAND</var> 
            </second>   
            <user_input_attn_obligor_desc>OBLIGOR ATTORNEY</user_input_attn_obligor_desc>                          
            </root>*
```

Comment: Is there a specific reason you're trying to use `sp_executesql` here? You can reference SQL columns and variables directly inside XPath expressions, e.g.: `sql:variable("@LS_NODE_NAME")`

Comment: Aside... as per [replace value of (XML DML)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/xml/replace-value-of-xml-dml) _Expression1 Identifies a node whose value is to be updated. It must identify only a single node._ In other words if you need to make multiple modifications they must be done in separate `.modify()` operations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using XML `modify()` the [`replace` operation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/xml/replace-value-of-xml-dml) must target a single node:

> *Expression1*
>
> Identifies a node whose value is to be updated. It must identify only a single node. That is, Expression1 must be a static singleton. If the XML is typed, the type of the node must be a simple type.

This means that to replace the contents of two separate nodes you will need two separate operations.

SQL Server also supports two XQuery Extension Functions, [`sql:column()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/xquery/xquery-extension-functions-sql-column) and [`sql:variable()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/xquery/xquery-extension-functions-sql-variable), which allow you to reference column and variable values from within expressions.

We can utilize `sql:variable()` to simplify your code to avoid the use of `sp_executesql`...

```sql
declare @LS_NODE_NAME nvarchar(100) = N'user_input_attn_obligee_desc',
        @LS_NAME_DESC  nvarchar(100) = N'EDWIN CHAND',
        @LS_DOCUMENT_XML xml = N'<root>
  <first>
    <var name="user_input_attn_obligee_desc">OBLIGEE ATTORNEY</var>
  </first>
  <second>
    <var name="user_input_attn_obligee_desc">saravanan</var>
  </second>
  <user_input_attn_obligor_desc>OBLIGOR ATTORNEY</user_input_attn_obligor_desc>
</root>';

set @LS_DOCUMENT_XML.modify(N'
  replace value of (/root/first/var[@name=sql:variable("@LS_NODE_NAME")]/text())[1]
  with sql:variable("@LS_NAME_DESC")
  ');

set @LS_DOCUMENT_XML.modify(N'
  replace value of (/root/second/var[@name=sql:variable("@LS_NODE_NAME")]/text())[1]
  with sql:variable("@LS_NAME_DESC")
  ');

select @LS_DOCUMENT_XML;
```

This yields the result:

```xml
<root>
    <first>
        <var name="user_input_attn_obligee_desc">EDWIN CHAND</var>
    </first>
    <second>
        <var name="user_input_attn_obligee_desc">EDWIN CHAND</var>
    </second>
    <user_input_attn_obligor_desc>OBLIGOR ATTORNEY</user_input_attn_obligor_desc>
</root>
```

---

*To address subsequent comments from the OP...*

The XPath query used in XML modify() has a number of limitations that prevent you from using simple solutions such as alternating paths (`/root/(first,second)/var[@name=sql:variable("@LS_NODE_NAME")]/text()[1]`) or replacing `[1]` with something like `[sql:variable("@NodeIndex")]` in a while loop.

If you don't know ahead of time how many nodes need to be matched, or the specific XPath for all of the elements, it is possible to use the `//` (descendant-or-self) axis specifier along with the XML [`exist()` method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/xml/exist-method-xml-data-type) and then simply replace the `text()` for nodes that don't already match, such as with the following SQL...

```sql
declare @ModifyCount int = 0;
while (@ModifyCount < 10 and @LS_DOCUMENT_XML.exist('//var[@name=sql:variable("@LS_NODE_NAME")][text()!=sql:variable("@LS_NAME_DESC")]') = 1)
begin
  set @LS_DOCUMENT_XML.modify(N'
    replace value of (//var[@name=sql:variable("@LS_NODE_NAME")][text()!=sql:variable("@LS_NAME_DESC")]/text())[1]
    with sql:variable("@LS_NAME_DESC")
    ');
  set @ModifyCount += 1;
end
select @ModifyCount, @LS_DOCUMENT_XML;
```

The problems with this, though, include:

1. `//var` isn't paying attention to any ascendant node hierarchy, so may not always target the path(s) you expect.
2. So as to avoid infinite loops do not trust `exist()` by itself - always include a Guard Counter such as the `@ModifyCount` with its limit of `10` recursions.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. For example I gave 2 occurrence of the same node. but in the real time do not know how many time it will come in the xml. So, in that situation we can't able to mention as /root/first/...  and/root/second/... right?. Is there any possibility to iterate through node?

Comment: same logic done in DB2 but i dont know how  iterate in sql server. below is the DB2 Query :SELECT 
XMLQUERY ('transform copy $new := $d1 modify for $xnode in $new/root//var[@name=$element_name] 
return do replace value of $xnode with $d

Comment: return $new' PASSING xmlparse(document'<root><first><var name="user_input_attn_obligee_desc">OBLIGEE ATTORNEY</var></first> 
<second><var name="user_input_attn_obligee_desc">saravanan</var></second> </root>') AS "d1", 'EDWIN CHAND' AS "d", 'user_input_attn_obligee_desc' AS "element_name")
 FROM SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1;